# Create directory tree (Java, Windows)

Tags: java

I am writing a Java (using Eclipse) program which creates a directory tree starting from a root directory. When I want to create the directory tree for "Program Files" (for example) the following exception is thrown: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException .
I have run java with administrator rights, there are more files and directories in the tree, but the same exception is thrown.
What should I do?

Comment: Probably related to UAC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works.   You may want to run program with "right click-> run as administrator"

Comment: try destination such as %USERPROFILE% or %TEMP%.  They are not restricted by UAC (Please add your code to question)

Comment: I have run the program as administrator. There are some directories that cannot be accessed by the administrator. I am looking for a way to access that directories programmatically because I don't want to change the properties of the directories.

Comment: You wrote _"there are some directories that cannot be accessed by the administrator. "_ .  Your java program  cannot do anything more than what you can do from a command line running as administrator.